# Why does xdg-open use Firefox rather than the default app according to xdg-mime?

Tags: xdg-open

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype my-time-sheet.ods 
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet

$ xdg-mime query default application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet
calc.desktop calc.desktop

$ xdg-open my-time-sheet.ods
```

One would expect that the last command would open calc.desktop, but instead the file path is opened in Firefox. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

> calc.desktop calc.desktop

If it is set correctly, "calc.desktop" is displayed only once.
This is repaired by re-setting.

```
xdg-mime default calc.desktop application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet
# (or edit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list)
```